# Optional extra character in regex character class

Tags: java, regex

I am using regex to match a String starting with `XY` and then 9 digits, like:

```
XY123456789
```

I am using this regex:

```
XY[0-9]{9}
```

Easy. But now I want to allow a an optional space in those digits.

So, the regex should match:

```
XY123456789
XY123 456789
XY1234567 89
```

I can use `XY[0-9 ]{9,10}`. But I just want to allow a maximum of one spaces, and only nine digits. So, the regex should not match:

```
XY1234567891
XY123 456 78
```

So `XY([0-9] ?){9}` or `XY[0-9] ?[0-9] ?[0-9] ?[0-9] ?[0-9] ?[0-9] ?[0-9] ?[0-9] ?[0-9]` doesn't work either.

Any ideas? Is there any way to specify the number of occurrences *inside* the character class, something like `XY[[0-9]*[ ]?]{9}` for example?

(In my specific case I'm using Java regex if that matters.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
^XY(?!\d*\h\d*\h)(?:\d(?:\h?\d){8})$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `XY` Match literally
- `(?!\d*\h\d*\h)` Negative lookahead, assert not 2 spaces
- `(?:\d(?:\h?\d){8})` Match 9 digits with an optional space
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4GcRGx/1)

In Java

```
String regex = "^XY(?!\\d*\\h\\d*\\h)(?:\\d(?:\\h?\\d){8})$";
```

Comment: Damn, I knew the answer would be some black magic regex